How to determine order from Vertex AI object detection, for images trained when exporting model to TFLite file?
I am exporting my trained object detection model, and then consuming the TFLite file with https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-fast-tflite to run on mobile device.  The output of the model is clearly defined as:
 // 2. Run model with given input buffer synchronously
    const outputs = model.runSync([resized])

    // 3. Interpret outputs accordingly
    const detection_boxes = outputs[0]
    const detection_classes = outputs[1]
    const detection_scores = outputs[2]
    const num_detections = outputs[3]

The outputs are ordered based on high > low scores and all associated outputs are respective of that order.
In this case, detection_classes is an ordered array with an index value: 0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 7.  In this case value can be used to look up what the underlying label value is on your model.
However, I have NO clue how my Google VertexAI order is respective to the training of the model.
I need to make a mappable object so that the first index, if it's value is 1 maps to whatever is item 1 in the model label itself.

Hi @Phil , could you please clarify your expectation .You want to mapp object with same value like 1:1,2:2 . Can you provide some example . To determine the order exporting model you can refer to this prediction data format . Let me know if this helps or not .

thanks @SouravDutta.  Yes I think the Prediction data format link is what I am looking for, except that is for "tabular" data.  I am looking for object detection image data, exported to TFLite: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/export/export-edge-model#output-files
As you can see there is no dictionary output.  Is there a more straight forward way to extract the dictionary so I can better map the results to human readible text?

HI @Phil Lucks , it appears that this issue has to be investigated further , so if you have a support plan please create a new support case  . Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.
